# List comp variable as a range argument using nested list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I am working on understanding this list comprehension but am left with more questions:

```
x = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(3)]
print(x)
>>>[[],[0],[0,1]]
```

As far as I understand, this would be broken down accordingly:

```
x = []
for r in range(3):
  for c in range(r):
    x.append(c)
print(x)
>>>[0,0,1]
```

However my unpacked version doesn't return a list of lists like the list comprehension.
My biggest questions are:

1) what does range(r) become in this situation?
2) how can I correct my for loops to make the same output as the list comprehension?

3) why does the list comprehension make a list of lists that it did?

Comment: You're forgetting to initialise the inner list at each iteration of your outer loop.

Comment: why not `for r in range(3): x.append(list(range(r)))`

Comment: why not just using comprehensions and drop the loops?

Answer (score 4):

Your unpacked version is not the same as the list comprehension one, they are not equivalent. An equivalent to the list comprehension one would be:

```
a = []
for r in range(3):
    x = []
    for c in range(r):
        x.append(c)
    a.append(x)
print(a)
>>> [[],[0],[0,1]]
```

See that in the list comprehesion you are creating a new list per iteration, while in the unpacked example you just append to the same one.

A list comprehension example of the unpacked version you gave would be:

```
x = [c for r in range(3) for c in range(r)]
```